# Go program to generate S3 presigned PUT URL

Tags: go, amazon-web-services

I'm have a made a simple Go program to generate a s3 presigned put url:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type Configuration struct {
  Bucket string
}

func main() {
    var configuration Configuration
    // Add Bucket to configuration from environment variable
    // e.g:
    //    CONFIGURATION_BUCKET -> configuration.Bucket
    err := envconfig.Process("configuration", &configuration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
      SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
      Bucket: aws.String(configuration.Bucket),
      Key: aws.String("default"),
    })

    url, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("Url is", url)
}
```

I would like to ask for help to turn into a more modular code / idiomatic. This is my first code written in Go, and I have mainly a JavaScript background, so I'm used to use asynchronous programming with callbacks (now Promises, async/await), and in Go things are very different (there are no classes, for example).

Comment: [Similar question](/q/188159/9357)